# Uncaught Error: no data returned for views/AgeTypes.fragment.xml

Tags: javascript, popover, sapui5

My AgeTypes.fragment.xml is like :

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">

    <ResponsivePopover
        id="popAgeTypes" class="sapUiPopupWithPadding"
        afterClose="onAgeTypesClosed"
        placement="Auto" showHeader="false" >
        <beginButton>
            <Button text="OK" press="onAgeTypeChanged" /> 
        </beginButton>
        <content>

        <List id="ageTypes" mode="MultiSelect"
            includeItemInSelection="true"
            items="{...}">

            <items>...</items>
        </List>
        </content>
    </ResponsivePopover>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

and in my view there is a button to open this popover fragment when it's pressed. My button xml is :

```
<m:Button id="ageTypesId" text="Ages" icon="sap-icon://person-placeholder"
                press="onAgeTypeSelect"/>
```

in my controller :

```
//this method is triggered when user press button.
onAgeTypeSelect: function(oEvent){
    this.popAgeTypes = sap.ui.xmlfragment( App.ComponentName + ".views.AgeTypes", this);
    this.getView().addDependent(this.popAgeTypes);
    this.popAgeTypes.openBy(oEvent.getSource());
},

//when user select items from responsive popover list item
onAgeTypeChanged: function(oEvent) {
    //taking selected items and doing some business.
    this.popAgeTypes.close();
    this.popAgeTypes.destroy();
},

//and this code is triggered when afterClose method of Responsive popover work
onAgeTypesClosed : function(oEvent){
    if (this.popAgeTypes) {
        this.popAgeTypes.destroy();
    }
}
```

the most weird thing is I am able to open this Responsive Popover for few minutes long or maybe more. Before that time I can open and close it properly but after some minutes I can't open it and I take **Uncaught Error: no data returned for .../views/AgeTypes.fragment.xml** error. I googled it but I couldn't find any useful infos.

Comment: Did you somehow solve this? I m currently facing the same problem...

Comment: I don't exactly remember what kind of situation I got this error. Sorry for that. But now it is working and working codes are nearly same with these codes. Make sure you wrote list items path right and to avoid dublicate id error don't assign an id in xml. And also try to clean your cache. I hope these solutions can help you.

Comment: thx - I'll have a look at this. After further investigation it seems like only the latest chrome version is throwing this error - other browsers still work. Somehow it is working when clearing the cache, but only once :D

Comment: it seems I will never be able to understand why these errors show up or why start to work :p

Comment: Same problem: 1. It works sporadically, 2. It happens only in Chrome (my version: 48.0.2564.97 64bit), 3. Dev Tools report Content-Length=1335, Content-Type=application/xml, but when I look at the "Response" tab, it says "This request has no response data available"

Answer (score 0):

i'm testing that if you open your gmail account before using your UI5 app in Chrome 48.0.2564.97 than the x.fragment.xml will not give you the error.

Comment: Sorry but I haven't enough reputations to comment main post.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same or at least a similar problem. (Uncaught Error: no data returned for ...). In my case all but first OPA tests failed.
After updating my Google Chrome from 48.0.2564.97 to 48.0.2564.103 the issue is gone.

Best regards,
Sebastian